# Dropdown Functions Work in 2010 but not in 2007

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2010

Ok - here's what I have.
An Excel file that asks a User to fill out some fields.

The first sheet has some fields to fill out. 
To assist the User, some fields are dropdowns. This is to ensure that the correct index values are used.

The User clicks on a cell (in this case N65) and that cell displays a dropdown.
The values displayed are from Col 1 of a range on a separate sheet.
The User selects a Col 1 value (the description in my case).
The corresponding row's Col 2 value (index value in my case) is saved to another cell on the sheet that has this bit of function code in it.

ta-da. das it.

Works great in 2010.

When a user opens the file using 2007, no dropdown appears.

Here is what goes into the destination cell, the cell that will ultimately end up holding the index value from Col 2. In this case the sheet is named Craft.

=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(N65,Craft!$A$2:$B$501,2,FALSE)),"",(VLOOKUP(N65,Craft!$A$2:$B$501,2,FALSE)))

Here is a variant of that same bit using named range instead.

=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(N65,Craft,2,FALSE)),"",(VLOOKUP(N65,Craft,2,FALSE)))

In either example, when using Excel 2010, the field, R69 for example, ends up populated with the Col 2 value after User selects a Col 1 value.

Basically wherever you stick that bit of function code, that field will get populated with whatever the VLOOKUP grabs from Col 2 for the row that contains User's Col 1 selection.

The Craft sheet just has two columns with 501 rows:

Select a Value

Craft Desc 1    |   Craft_1

Craft Desc 2    |   Craft_2

Etc...

Does anyone have an idea as to how I can get this working with Excel 2007 and 2010?

Thanks!

Comment: Are these dropdowns ActiveX components or possibly form objects object created by an event macro at run-time? Or are they simply in-cell Validation lists?

Comment: Thanks David
These are basically just really long data validations.
I have a cell that - in 2010 - becomes a dropdown when I put the function above in another cell. 
The dropdown shows Col1 and the corresponding Col2 value gets put in the cell with the function in it.
In your example, I am not sure what the error would be.
I have ISNA in there just to keep #NA or #VALUE from being put in the target cell, the one with the function in it.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: pnuts -
Yes , the function =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(N65,Craft,2,FALSE),"")  does the lookup part correctly.
The part that is missing is the Col1 values showing up as a dropdown in cell N65.
The function I used in my post - in 2010 - will create a dropdown of the Col1 values.
In 2007, nothing, but if you type in a Col1 value correctly then yes, you do get the corresponding Col2 value.
I'm really needing the dropdown of Col1 values.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: I ended up using pnuts suggestion.
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(DropDown,Codes,2,FALSE),"")
The way I got it to work was on the worksheet with the desc & code I selected the Desc column and named it and used that in the Data Validation because it seems to only work with a single column.
Then I named the range for both Desc & code for use with the VLOOKUP function and that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using pnuts suggestion. =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(DropDown,Codes,2,FALSE),"") The way I got it to work was on the worksheet with the desc & code I selected the Desc column and named it and used that in the Data Validation because it seems to only work with a single column. Then I named the range for both Desc & code for use with the VLOOKUP function and that worked.

Answer (score 1):

> When a user opens the file using 2007, no dropdown appears.

In Excel 2007 we had to create a range-name in order to use DataValidation with a List from another sheet, entering `=TheRangeName` in the `Source` box. In Excel 2010 this is not essential and, when defining the source, we can just highlight a range in another sheet. I suspect that this may be the issue.

You will need to correct the Data Validation settings to use `=TheRangeName`, instead of `=Sheet1!A1:A4`. On the Home tab click the Find & Select button and choose Data Validation. This will select all the cells on the current sheet that have Data Validation. Alternatively, click in a cell that you know has Data Validation and choose Go To Special from the Find & Select list; from here you can select all cells that contain the `Same` validation as the current cell(s). If you can't find any such cells then you'll need to recreate the validation(s) from scratch.

Comment: Andy
Thank you so much for answering.
I think I already tried that and got the same result.

"Here is a variant of that same bit using named range instead.

=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(N65,Craft,2,FALSE)),"",(VLOOKUP(N65,Craft,2,FALSE)))
"
Are you referring to the Source box as being the cell that I am expecting the dropdown to appear in?

Thanks for your help !